# How to get key of parent

Tags: javascript, node.js, firebase-realtime-database, google-cloud-functions

I just want to get the stripe customer ID whenever a new payment method is added to my database.

I'm new to realtime databases and I just need some guidance.

```
var newPaymentMethodRef = functions.database.ref('/stripe_customers/{uid}/newPaymentMethod');
var stripe_customers = functions.database.ref('/stripe_customers/{uid}');

 exports.newPaymentMethod = newPaymentMethodRef.onWrite(event => {
       console.log("uid = ${uid}");
       console.log("newPaymentMethod created");

 });
```

I've tried

```
event.key 
event.parent.key
event.ref("/stripe_customers/")
```

I'm obviously lost

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If the Stripe customer ID is the value that is passed in the `{uid}` part if the call to the database, you can get it with:

```
exports.newPaymentMethod = newPaymentMethodRef.onWrite((change, context) => {
   console.log(context.params.uid);
```

Also see the Firebase documentation on [Realtime Database triggers](https://firebase.google.com/docs/functions/database-events#reading_the_previous_value).

Comment: this worked! I was just getting a bit confused with the difference between change and context objects.